# Differential linear equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$(D^2-1)y=x\sin(x)+x^2e^x$

My particular solution is of the form :
$y_p=d_1\sin(x)+d_2\cos(x)+d_3x\sin(x)+d_4x\cos(x)+d_5xe^x+d_6x^2e^x+d_7x^3e^x$

I have been successful in correctly getting  the coefficient $d_1 ,d_2, d_3$ and $d_4$ but I am getting some difficulty in getting the latter coefficient.I get $d_5=1/4, d_6=-1/4$ and $d_7=1/6$ which according to the answer doesn't match. Can someone tell me my mistake?

Comment: I think you're missing a term of the form $e^x$..

Answer (score 1):

I am going to rewrite your $y_p$ as

$$y_p(x) = a\sin(x)+b\cos(x)+cx\sin(x)+dx\cos(x)+x e^x(e + f x + g x^2)$$

We have $(D^2-1)y_p(x)$ as

$-2 a \sin (x)-2 b \cos (x)-2 c x \sin (x)+2 c \cos (x)-2 d \sin (x)-2 d x \cos (x)+2 e e^x+4 f e^x x+2 f e^x+6 g e^x x^2+6 g e^x x$

Equating like terms, we get seven equations for the seven unknowns

$$\begin{align} -2b + 2 c &= 0 \\ -2d &= 0 \\ -2a - 2d & = 0 \\-2c &= 1 \\ 6g&=1 \\6g + 4 f &= 0 \\ 2e + 2 f &= 0\end{align}$$

Solving

$$a = 0, b = -\dfrac{1}{2}, c = -\dfrac{1}{2}, d = 0, e = \dfrac{1}{4}, f = -\dfrac{1}{4}, g = \dfrac{1}{6}$$

Compare this to [*Wolfram Alpha*](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%27+-+y+%3D+x+sin%28x%29+%2B+x%5E2+e%5E%28x%29) and it matches.

Maybe there is a mistake in the book's result or the problem is not written correctly.